# Leaking water from leaky pots

Tags: fluid-dynamics, water, porous-media

I have two absolutely identical pots with round bottoms. Each bottom has the same number of absolutely identical holes drilled in it. In the first pot, all the holes are quite far apart, while in the second, on the contrary, they form one dense group. (In this group, the distance between the holes is several times less than the diameter of the holes.)

[image]

Now I put the same volume of water in both pots.

Question 1. Will this water flow out of both pots in the same time or not?

Question 2. If the time will be different, then the rate at which the water flows out is affected by the arrangement of the holes. Then what physical law describes this relationship?

I think I once read that if a group of holes are close together, they can be thought of as one big hole. But I can't find the name of this law.

Comment: Do you mean two pots with equal cross-sections and flat bottoms?

Comment: It seems to me a very complicated comparison and the answer could depend on the actual value of holes diameter and interdistance in all possible combinations. Flow rates certainly at work.

Comment: Yes, I mean two absolutly equal pots with flat bottom.

Comment: I mean two cases. In first the distances between holes are greater that they diameter. In the second one the distances are smaller than thay diameter. I need a (common) physical law  that can explane the difference in the water flow.